# Sharepoint online - How to create url link to prefiltered list and let the filters to be editable

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

#### What I need

From an external app, I need to create url link to prefiltered sharepoint list. The filter value should be specified in the URL.

When user click the link, he should be able to manually edit or remove the filter.

### What I have

My URL currently looks like this

```
/sites/MySite/MyList/Forms/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=Title&FilterType1=Text&FilterValue1=abc&useFiltersInViewXml=1
```

### Problem

Using this URL, the filters seems to be static and user cannot remove them. If the users click on Clear filters, the list is reloaded, but the url filters stays.

### Question

How do I create link to prefiltered sharepoint list and let user to edit the filters?

[image: sharepoint screenshot]

Comment: Reloaded list have all items or filtered items?